# Get the directory structure of a tgz file in python

Tags: python, gzip, listdir

I have a `.tgz` file that contains multiple text files.  I can read it in Python using the `gzip` module, and I see that the first line contains some information about the subsequent file, but it is unclear how I can properly iterate through the files in Python.  I would like to be able to do something like:

```
for file in tgzFile:
  read file
  do stuff for file
```

I can read each line of the gzipped file, and I could attempt to identify the start of a file from the contents of the line, but I would prefer a cleaner method.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("file.tgz")
for file in tar.getmembers():
    print file.name
```

Tar.getmembers() returns a list of TarInfo objects which can be used accordingly.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarInfo